# Proper way to search for elements in divs with given class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="therarepets">
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/abc">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/def">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
 </div>

    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/vwx">OutsideLinkDontWant.</a>

<div class="thegoodpets">
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/ghi">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/jkl">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/stu">CanHaveMoreWantedLinks.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/mno">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://otherpetshop.com/zzz">OuterLinkDontWant.</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thebadpets">
    <div class="badpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/pqr">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to search for links only in divs with "chooseme" classes (I add that class via javascript to those divs which I'm interested in), and get their number, or change their color - just for simple example.

These are:

- divs with rarepet class, which has a span with content of NEW
- and divs with goodpet class, which has a span with content of NEW

I don't want any badpet divs, nor divs without the NEW text span.

I managed to do the selection of the divs and adding the class (I'm not sure if this is the best way):

```
$('.rarepet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
$('.goodpet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
```

but I can't reach the links from these divs. (In this example there should be 3 divs with the chooseme class: `<div class="pet chooseme">` .) I can only get links from the whole document:

```
var petlinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0;i<petlinks.length;i++){
    var href = petlinks[i].href;
    if(href.indexOf('examplepetshop.com') !=-1){
        (petlinks[i].href).length;
    }
}
```

How could I run `getElementsByTagName('a');` only with class "chooseme"? The next is not working:

```
var petlinks = document.getElementsByTagName('.chooseme > a');
```

And anything else I've tried gave errors. Like:

```
var wantedlist = document.getElementsByClassName('chooseme');
var petlinks = wantedlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName('.chooseme > a')` doesn't work because `.getElementsByTagName()` expects a html tag and not a selector ([`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/querySelector) and [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/querySelectorAll) "understand" CSS selectors). And for the last example: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of nodes. Hence you would have to call `.getElementsByTagName('a')` on every node in the list.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

Since you started to use jQuery to add class names, what about this snippet to search for links?

```js
$('.rarepet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
$('.goodpet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
var wantedlist = $('.chooseme a')
  .map(function(index, link) {
    return link.href;
  })
  .toArray()
  .filter(function(link) {
    return link.indexOf('examplepetshop.com') > -1;
  })

console.log(wantedlist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="therarepets">
  <div class="rarepet">
    <span>OLD</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/abc">Buy it.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rarepet">
    <span>NEW</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/def">Buy it.</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="http://examplepetshop.com/vwx">OutsideLinkDontWant.</a>

<div class="thegoodpets">
  <div class="goodpet">
    <span>OLD</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/ghi">Buy it.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="goodpet">
    <span>NEW</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/jkl">Buy it.</a>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/stu">CanHaveMoreWantedLinks.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="goodpet">
    <span>NEW</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/mno">Buy it.</a>
    <a href="http://otherpetshop.com/zzz">OuterLinkDontWant.</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thebadpets">
  <div class="badpet">
    <span>NEW</span>
    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/pqr">Buy it.</a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I either get "wantedlist.indexOf is not a function" or "wantedlist.getElementsByTagName is not a function", not sure which lines you changed. (The last link we should not get, the rest are good ones yes.)

Comment: @JaSon you only need 3 lines of code to solve your task. 1 and 2 are yours which add a class `$('.rarepet:has.....` and the 3rd one is the one from my answer.

Comment: @JaSon `wantedlist` is an array-like jQuery object which doesn't have a `.indexOf()` method. The same for `.getElementsByTagName()` which is DOM method.

Comment: @JaSon I updated my answer. Check out a link provided

Comment: Oh, I see, you changed all of that block. Thanks! Only problem I have with it is I need only links which contains "examplepetshop.com", and throw out the rest.

Comment: @JaSon I updated answer again including a runnable snippet. Take a look at `.filter` javascript method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Examples

Comment: @vlad.golubev Thank you very much. (Though I'll need some more time playing around with it to be able to implement into my not-this-simple project, haha.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it more complicated than it has to be. You already use jQuery to add the class. Just keep using jQuery to select it now.

```
$('.chooseme')
```

This gives you the all the divs with the chooseme class. Then you just chain selectors. JQuery works similar to CSS in that. It lets you either use multiple selectors in the same statement, either comma separated which just selects multiple elements or space separated which like `div a` which gives you all the a tags in a div. So in your case you want to use:

```
$('.chooseme a')
```

After that, you map over it and return the href for each a element.

```
$('.chooseme a').map(function(index, link) {return link.href});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code, hope it will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.rarepet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
   $('.goodpet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');

   var total_href = 0;
   $( "a" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('chooseme')){
     console.log('href :',total_href ,$( this ).attr('href'));
     total_href = total_href+1;
    }
    
   });

   console.log('total count of href in chooseme class:',total_href);
   $('.chooseme a').css('color', 'red');
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="therarepets">
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/abc">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/def">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
 </div>

    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/vwx">OutsideLinkDontWant.</a>

<div class="thegoodpets">
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/ghi">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/jkl">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/stu">CanHaveMoreWantedLinks.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/mno">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://otherpetshop.com/zzz">OuterLinkDontWant.</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thebadpets">
    <div class="badpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/pqr">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another demo by filtering all `a` tags with `parent()` class `.chooseme`:

```js
$('.rarepet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');
$('.goodpet:has(span:contains("NEW"))').addClass('chooseme');

// links holds all links found inside chooseme class
var links = [];

// linkObj holds all 'a' tags element
var linkObj = $('a').filter(function(indx, elem){
    if ($(elem).parent().hasClass('chooseme'))
    {
        // push all selected hrefs in links array
     links.push($(elem).attr('href'));
      
        // change color of that elem
        // can be done by another method outside this loop though
        // e.g. $('.chooseme a').css('color', 'red')
     $(elem).css('color', 'red'); 
        return true; // return this elem and store in linkObj
    }
});
console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="therarepets">
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/abc">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rarepet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/def">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
 </div>

    <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/vwx">OutsideLinkDontWant.</a>

<div class="thegoodpets">
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>OLD</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/ghi">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/jkl">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/stu">CanHaveMoreWantedLinks.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="goodpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/mno">Buy it.</a>
        <a href="http://otherpetshop.com/zzz">OuterLinkDontWant.</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thebadpets">
    <div class="badpet">
        <span>NEW</span>
        <a href="http://examplepetshop.com/pqr">Buy it.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```